# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10: RST, BitLocker and biometric login?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, xps, fingerprint-reader, rst

I have a Dell XPS 15 9500 with Windows 10 Pro already installed on its single SSD. I'd like to dual boot both Windows 10 Pro (or 11 Pro) and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on the single boot drive.
Both BitLocker and Rapid Storage Technology were active, but I only deactivated BitLocker to go on with the installation process, hoping for Ubuntu to recognize all existing disk partitions without having to switch from RST to AHCI.
Unfortunately, it didn't go as hoped.
I was wondering if there's a way to successfully dual boot these OSes without having to give up RST.
Moreover, I'd like to crypt both my partitions... is there a way to do so, like having BitLocker encrypt Windows 10 partition only and something similar on Ubuntu for Linux partition only?
Many people dealt with RST and BitLocker in similar situations, but wasn't quick enough to find discussions that covered precisely my scenario.

PS: I'd also be able to still use Windows Hello to login in my Win installation and maybe the fingerprint to login into Ubuntu... is this even possible?

Comment: Is SSD a SATA or NVMe drive? I have new Dell 5310 with NVMe and it used a vmd driver. No AHCI at all, but no SATA drives either. I installed with UEFI Secure boot on (forgot to turn it off, but it installed & dual boots), but had bitlocker & fast start up off. Expected I might need newer than 22.04, but it installed without issue. I first booted with full install on an external USB3 SSD drive with 22.04 as not sure install would work.

Comment: The SSD is of course NVMe. The issue was that the chipset was neither in SATA or AHCI modes, but in Intel RST mode. Ubuntu can probalby read some RST configurations, but in my case, with Windows 10 already installed, couldn't recognize the partition scheme of the SSD and therefore could not install properly. I had to deactivate Intel RST and switch the system to AHCI mode. Wasn't easy

Answer (score 0):

To successfully install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on the Dell XPS 15 in dual-boot, alongside the original Windows 10 installation from the laptop OEM, you need to switch the controller from RST to AHCI modes.
First, you need to disable the BitLocker encryption within Windows. You can type BitLocker into the Search bar, open the tool and follow the instructions... you need access to your Microsoft account to recover some security keys, but after that should not be easy.
Then you need to do the actual switch from RST to AHCI mode for the Storage controller.
The main guidelines could be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/
Unfortunately, for this very machine (and possibly for other more recent Intel laptops with NVMe SSDs), you need an additional step, so the procedure looks like that:

1. enter Windows 10 and backup everything you don't want to lose
2. open msconfig as admin and set Safe Boot as default boot option
3. reboot into Windows: Safe Boot should be enabled
4. while in Safe Boot mode, open regedit as administrator and do the
   Registry key changes in the guide above
5. reboot into UEFI, and in the Storage section set AHCI instead of
   RAIDon
6. reboot into Windows: should still be in Safe Boot, but should boot properly
7. while in Windows Safe Boot, open msconfig again and reset the default boot option to normal (deselect Safe Boot)
8. reboot into Windows: should boot normally, not in Safe Mode
9. verify in Device Manager that the Storage controller is running as AHCI or NVMe
10. shrink Windows 10 partition on the drive to create an empty one for Ubuntu to install
11. install Ubuntu through your favourite method: the installer should see Windows 10 partition no problem

Hope you find this helpful.

*Haven't tried activating biometric login and other stuff like that, as I'm facing another issue in Ubuntu 22.04 after completing the installation. The issue is not linked to what this thread deals with, so I'll open a new thread if needed.
When that issue will be solved, I'll get back to multi-OS encryption and biomteric login into Ubuntu.*